# How Can I create this Slime dripping down effect?

Tags: modeling, effects

I want to create this cool looking Slime Effect in Blender with a Mesh:

[image: Screenshot]

I researched a bit for an answer, but I could not find something useful.

To be clear I want to use a basic Mesh like a Cube or a Cylinder and edit it until it looks like this and I don't want to make a render with this.
I want to export the map to Unity and thats why it would be the best if I would use a basic mesh for material and stuff.

The slime itself should be dripping down a wall.

My Question is which Mesh should I use and with which tools can I achieve this effect.
Maybe you can suggest a good tutorial or you can explain me how to achieve this effect.

Here are some more examples from what I meant:

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You could use the viscosity solver in blender to make a thick, drippy liquid that is dripping from the wall. Then, just render the frame with the one suitable. But to be honest, blender isn't made for this stuff and the tool for this in photoshop.

Comment: this is also possible with dynamic paint. So search for "blender dynamic paint tutorial" in google.... ;)

Comment: Thanks for the Tips but thats not what I directly asked for. It is my fault that I haven't said that I want to export the map to Unity and not render it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a node group.  Either of these *Math -> Divide* nodes should give you something to start from.  There are places where this produces some weird lines due to the subtract operations, just move the *Location* on the *Mapping* node around until you get something workable.

[image]